# Setting up a Raspberry Pi to monitor on Multiple Channels with Nexmon Drivers

Tags: networking, wireless, multiple-monitors, raspberrypi, network-monitoring

I'm pretty far in the process of using a Raspberry Pi to monitor network traffic, using tcpdump.  I then send the file to a kali linux desktop, using scp.  Then I view the data in wireshark.  I'd like to be able to view multiple channels worth of network traffic at once, so I am curious how I can set up a python script or wlan0 to be able to do this.

I do know how to set the frequency of wlan0 using "sudo iw dev wlan0 set freq 2462" for one channel.

Sincerely,
Michael

P.S. this is my first project with network monitoring, and networking in general, so please bear with me.